# Latex for-and in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need to write equation as shown in the attached image in LaTex. So far, I have written it like shown below but I can't figure out how to separate (or write properly) the "for" and "and" part of the equation similar to that shown in the image.

```
\begin{equation}    
P_d(\delta_L)=P_p(\delta_S,L_S)     for \delta_S>\delta_{0S} and \delta_L<\delta_{0L}
\end{equation}
```

[image]
I request for help to correct the code. Thank you

Comment: I tend to use `\qquad\text{for $\delta_S>\delta_{0S}$ and $\delta_L<\delta_{0L}$}`, this way the math and condition has proper semantic markup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `align*`.

[image: align]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}    
P_d(\delta_L) &= P_p(\delta_S,L_S)\\
&\phantom{{}={}}\text{for $\delta_S>\delta_{0S}$ and $\delta_L<\delta_{0L}$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Numbered...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  
\begin{aligned}[b]  
P_d(\delta_L)={}&P_p(\delta_S,L_S)\\
  & \text{for } \delta_S>\delta_{0S} \text{ and } \delta_L<\delta_{0L}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your picture hints you're using a two-column format. Here's my proposal with `multlined`:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[b][0.66\displaywidth]
P_d(\delta_L)=P_p(\delta_S,L_S) \\
\text{for $\delta_S>\delta_{0S}$ and $\delta_L<\delta_{0L}$}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package is just to provide context. The `newtx...` packages are to get Times-like fonts as in your picture.

[image]

Comment: Hi. How works `\begin{multlined}[b][0.66\displaywidth]`? It is the first time that I have seen `multlined`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano It's an addition made by `mathtools`.

Comment: Ok. I have much appreciated your comment. Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

```
   \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}l}    
    $P_d(\delta_L) =$ & $ P_p(\delta_S,L_S)$\\
          &\text{for $\delta_S>\delta_{0S}$ and 
      $\delta_L<\delta_{0L}$}
   \end{tabular}
   \end{document}
```

How about testing this? Simpler and has more freedom.